# Mutilple JSON root element errors

Tags: json, web-scraping

The file I am calling is JSON with padding and I have done my simple coding to remove the padding but it appears by stringing together multiple JSON strings the formatting is not correct and I get root element errors.

I am using the output of the python program and running it through an online JSON formatter and validator website to check my output. I am a learner so please bear with my inexperience. All help appreciated.

```
import json
import re
import requests
        
payload = {}
headers = {}
     
        for race in range(1, 3):
            url = f"https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.static/2018-01-01/flemington/sectionaltimes/race-{race}.json?callback=sectionaltimes_callback"
            response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
          
            strip = 'sectionaltimes_callback'
            string = response.text
            repl =''
        
            result = re.sub(strip, repl, string)
            print(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way of obtaining the data you're looking for:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

      
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0',
       'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5'}
for race in range(1, 3):
    url = f"https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.static/2018-01-01/flemington/sectionaltimes/race-{race}.json?callback=sectionaltimes_callback"
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    json_obj = json.loads(r.text.split('sectionaltimes_callback(')[1].rsplit(')', 1)[0])
    df = pd.DataFrame(json_obj['Horses'])
    print(df)
```

This would return (print out in terminal) a dataframe for each race:

```
Comment FinalPosition   FinalPositionAbbreviation   FullName    SaddleNumber    HorseUrl    SilkUrl Trainer TrainerUrl  Jockey  ... DistanceVarToWinner SixHundredMetresTime    TwoHundredMetresTime    Early   Mid Late    OverallPeakSpeed    PeakSpeedLocation   OverallAvgSpeed DistanceFromRail
0   Resumes. Showed pace to lead well off the rail...   1   1st Crossing the Abbey  2   /horses/crossing-the-abbey  //s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.silk...   T.Hughes    /trainers/tim-hughes    C.Williams  ...     32.84   11.43   57.4    68.2    65.3    68.9    400m    63.3    0.8
1   Same sire as Katy's Daughter out of dual stake...   2   2nd Khulaasa    5   /horses/khulaasa    //s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.silk...   D. & B.Hayes & T.Dabernig   /trainers/david-hayes   D.Oliver    ... 0   32.61   11.29   56.6    68.4    66.0    69.2    700m    63.4    1.2
2   Trialled nicely before pleasing debut in what ...   3   3rd Graceful Star   4   /horses/graceful-star   //s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.silk...   D. & B.Hayes & T.Dabernig   /trainers/david-hayes   A.Mallyon   ... 0   33.10   11.56   56.9    67.4    64.8    68.5    400m    62.8    4.4
3   Sat second at debut, hampered at the 700m then...   4   4th Carnina 1   /horses/carnina //s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.silk...   T.Busuttin & N.Young    /trainers/trent-busuttin    B.Mertens   ... +1  33.30   11.80   56.9    68.2    63.9    68.9    400m    62.7    3.0
4   $75k yearling by a Magic Millions winner out o...   5   5th Mirette 7   /horses/mirette //s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.silk...   A.Alexander /trainers/archie-alexander  J.Childs    ... 0   33.53   11.89   57.0    67.9    63.5    68.5    700m    62.5    3.8
5   $95k yearling by same sire as Pinot out of a s...   6   6th Dark Confidant  3   /horses/dark-confidant  //s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.silk...   D. & B.Hayes & T.Dabernig   /trainers/david-hayes   D.Dunn  ... +2  33.74   11.91   56.4    67.1    63.3    68.8    700m    61.9    5.0
6   Same sire as Vega Magic out of imported stakes...   7   7th La Celestina    6   /horses/la-celestina    //s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.silk...   D.R.Brideoake   /trainers/david-brideoake   D.M.Lane    ... +1  34.46   12.27   57.5    67.3    61.4    68.2    700m    61.7    0.8
7 rows × 29 columns

Comment FinalPosition   FinalPositionAbbreviation   FullName    SaddleNumber    HorseUrl    SilkUrl Trainer TrainerUrl  Jockey  ... DistanceVarToWinner SixHundredMetresTime    TwoHundredMetresTime    Early   Mid Late    OverallPeakSpeed    PeakSpeedLocation   OverallAvgSpeed DistanceFromRail
0   Game in defeat both runs this campaign. Better...   1   1st Wise Hero   2   /horses/wise-hero   //s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.silk...   J.W.Price   /trainers/john-price    S.M.Thornton    ...     33.13   11.43   55.4    62.7    65.5    68.2    300m    61.7    0.7
1   Two runs since racing wide over this trip at C...   2   2nd Just Hifalutin  5   /horses/just-hifalutin  //s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.silk...   E.Jusufovic /trainers/enver-jusufovic   L.Currie    ... +3  32.75   11.37   53.1    63.8    65.8    68.5    400m    61.7    3.3
2   Did a bit of early work at Seymour and was not...   3   3rd King Kohei  10  /horses/king-kohei  //s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.silk...   Michael & Luke Cerchi   /trainers/mick-cerchi   
[...]
```

Comment: You could do `df.to_csv('table_name.csv')`, which would save the dataframe to disk, as csv. Or you could do `df.to_excel("table_name.xlsx") `. Relevant documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: Thank you introduced your recommendation and works a treat. I have dumped output into excel but appears that not all the data/headings are coming across, the  file has 76 headings. The data output is like this :Comment FinalPosition FinalPositionAbbreviation FullName SaddleNumber HorseUrl SilkUrl Trainer TrainerUrl Jockey JockeyUrl SectionalTimes SplitTimes StartPosition BarrierNumber RaceTime TimeVarToWinner BeatenMargin DistanceRun DistanceVarToWinner SixHundredMetresTime TwoHundredMetresTime Early Mid Late OverallPeakSpeed PeakSpeedLocation OverallAvgSpeed DistanceFromRail

Comment: Only bringing across 29 columns not 76

Comment: Also if I change the range to 9 it does not bring the data from all races just the original extract but if I print the df it prints all races but only with 29 columns not 76.

Comment: Think I have worked it out I have include the following pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

Comment: Did you inspect that json object? Did you print out df.shape, to see how many columns the dataframe has? Those dataframes are only taking 'Horses' out of the json object. Are there any other fields you might need, in json? These are all separate questions: your original one (about the errors in JSON) was solved.

Comment: I am learning on the run. I get maximum columns in df print but need to now work out the excel fix. I really appreciate your assistance and apologise for my shortcomings

Comment: No need for apologizing. Just inspect that big json object, and decide what information need from it. Dataframes based on ['Horses'] field have 29 columns.

Comment: So to understand, there is other data nested and I need to call out that identifier to get it into the Dataframe. For example I can see sectionaltimes and splittimes

Comment: That's right, there (might be, I haven't spent that much time inspecting that json file) other elements in the object, beside 'Horses'.